# Scrolling with WKWebview with Swift 4

Tags: html, ios, uiscrollview, swift4, wkwebview

I have a `WKWebview` properly showing html content from local webfiles. The html is much wider than the screen and I need to enable horizontal scrolling. Is this possible with just the `WKWebview` or do I need to make the `WKWebview` a subview of a `UIScrollView`?

Answer (score 0):

Add `Javascript` to fix screen width and height as per device.

Use this code:

```
NSString *js = @"var metaTag=document.createElement('meta');"
"metaTag.name = \"viewport\";"
"metaTag.content = \"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0\";"
"document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(metaTag);";

WKUserScript *script = [[WKUserScript alloc] initWithSource:js injectionTime:WKUserScriptInjectionTimeAtDocumentEnd forMainFrameOnly:YES];
[_WebView.configuration.userContentController addUserScript:script];
```

In Swift

```
let js = """
var metaTag=document.createElement('meta');\
metaTag.name = "viewport";\
metaTag.content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0";\
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(metaTag);
"""

let script = WKUserScript(source: js, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true)
self.webView.configuration.userContentController.addUserScript(script)
```

Comment: Unfortunatley, I do not know Objective-C very well. Could you answer in Swift 4?